# Difference between if and if exists()?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Take any given queryset, `qs = QS.objects.filter(active=True)`

Is there i difference between:

```
if qs:
```

and

```
if qs.exists():
```

regarding load on the db, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference:

- `if qs` will use the [`__nonzero__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L144) method of the `QuerySet` object, which calls `_fetch_all` which will in turn actually execute a full query (that's how I interpret it anyway).
- `exists()` does something more efficient, as [noted by Ewan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22090751/98057). That's why this method... exists.

So, in short, use `exists()` when you *only* need to check for existence since that's what it's for.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists)

> Returns `True` if the QuerySet contains any results, and `False` if not. This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal QuerySet query.
>
> `exists()` is useful for searches relating to both object membership in a QuerySet and to the existence of any objects in a QuerySet, particularly in the context of a large QuerySet.

However they then go on to show a few examples and conclude that `if qs` vs `if qs.exists()` needs a large queryset for efficiency gains.

A final caveat from the documentation:

> Additionally, if a `some_queryset` has not yet been evaluated, but you know that it will be at some point, then using `some_queryset.exists()` will do **more overall work** (one query for the existence check plus an extra one to later retrieve the results) than simply using `bool(some_queryset)`, which retrieves the results and then checks if any were returned.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that caveat. I've always tried to use `.exists()`, but after testing some code, I was surprised to see that it took longer and ran more SQL queries when I added `.exists()`. I think the caveat explains why that was happening

Answer (score 0):

It produces the same result. From the help on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

**exists()**

Returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not.

**bool()**

Testing a QuerySet in a boolean context, ..., will cause the query to be executed. If there is at least one result, the QuerySet is True, otherwise False.

Comment: "Note: Don’t use this if all you want to do is determine if at least one result exists, and don’t need the actual objects. It’s more efficient to use exists() (see below)."